# Questions about MIPS Codes

Tags: mips

**How to write the following into MIPS instructions?**

- `$t0=$t1`
- `if ($t6<$t7) go to Label.`

Answer (score 1):

$t0 is not reserved for zero. $t0 is a temporary register that can store any value. The register $zero is reserved/hard-wired to zero. We would want to "branch" to "Label" if $t6 is "less than" $t7, so use the branch on less than instruction blt. The code would look like:

add $t0,$zero,$t1
blt $t6,$t7,Label

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the registers are already loaded with the right data.

So for `$t2 = $t3`, adding `$t3` to register zero and storing it in `$t2` will work so this is how it would look like :

`add $t2,$t3,$t0`  - assuming $t0 is reserved for zero like most versions of mips.

for `if $t4`, we need a branch statement, not sure what you want to compare it to, but look at this guide - should give enough instructions about how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

your following rubbish:

> $t0=$t1
>
> if ($t6 less than $t7) go to Label

would be converted to MIPS like:

> move $t0,$t1 # or use instruction instead (add $t0,$zero,$t1)|(addi $t0,$t1,0)
>
> slt $t2,$t6,$t7 # if $t6less than $t7 set $t2=1
>
> bgtz $t2,foo # if $t2=0 goto foo, and foo is the label that you want to move to

Comment: `bgtz $t2,foo` will jump to foo if  **$t2 > 0** not $t2 = 0